# Comparing Strings in VBA

Tags: string, vba, compare

I have a basic programming background and have been self sufficient for many years but this problem I can't seem to solve. I have a program in VBA and I need to compare two strings. I have tried using the following methods to compare my strings below but to no avail:

```
//Assume Cells(1, 1).Value = "Cat"

Dim A As String, B As String

A="Cat"

B=Cell(1, 1).Value

If A=B Then...

If A Like B Then...

If StrCmp(A=B, 1)=0 Then...

I've even tried inputting the Strings straight into the code to see if it would work:

If "Cat" = "Cat" Then...

If "Cat" Like "Cat" Then...

If StrCmp("Cat" = "Cat", 1) Then...
```

VBA for some reason does not recognize these strings as equals. When going through Debugger it shows that StrComp returns 1. Do my strings have different Char lengths? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you see if you do `B = "@@@" + Cell(1, 1).Value + "@@@"`?  Any extra spaces?  Tried wrapping `B` with `Trim()`?

Comment: Yes and VBA still still returns a 1 with StrComp()

Comment: I think you're using `StrComp` incorrectly.  But the other functions should work (and indeed *do* work when I test them).

Comment: Am I using it wrong? And I dont know Keep trying 
If "D555177" Like "D555177" then... but im not getting anything. Is it because i have integers in the string? It shouldn't matter right?

Comment: see my answer below, you're certainly using it wrong, comparing a boolean to an integer.

Comment: That last statement `If "D555177" Like "D555177"` evaluates `True` for me, as well.

Comment: Don't put the equals sign inside StrComp. Separate text strings with a comma. This is wrong: `If StrCmp(A=B, 1)=0 Then`. Use this: `If StrCmp(A, B, 1)=0 Then`

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems to be an Excel bug. I have two identical strings in different variable. However, the StrCmp return 'false'.
[screenshot from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZyT1.png) If I try the message box, it also returns false. Now the interesting thing: If I copy the string from the debugger window and paste it again. The same test would result in true. I assume this means there are some hidden characters that prevent the string to be equal which survive the trim() command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Posting as answer because it doesn't fit in the comments:

I find it hard to believe that something like:

```
MsgBox "Cat" = "Cat"
```

Would not display `True` on your machine.  Please verify.

However, I do observe that you are most certainly using `StrComp` function incorrectly.

The proper use is `StrComp(string, anotherstring, [comparison type optional])`

When you do `StrComp(A=B, 1)` you are essentially asking it to compare whether a boolean (`A=B` will either evaluate to True or False) is equivalent to the integer `1`.  It is not, nor will it ever be.

When I run the following code, all four message boxes confirm that each statement evaluates to True.

```
Sub CompareStrings()
Dim A As String, B As String
A = "Cat"
B = Cells(1, 1).Value


MsgBox A = B

MsgBox A Like B

MsgBox StrComp(A, B) = 0 

MsgBox "Cat" = "Cat" 


End Sub
```

**Update from comments**

I don't see anything odd happening if I use an array, just FYI.  Example data used in the array:

[image]

Modified routine to use an array:

```
Sub CompareStrings()
Dim A As String, B() As Variant

A = "Cat"
B = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A8").Value)

For i = 1 To 8

    MsgBox A = B(i)

    MsgBox A Like B(i)

    MsgBox StrComp(A, B(i)) = 0

    MsgBox "Cat" = B(i)

Next

End Sub
```

What I would check is how you're instantiating the array. Range arrays (as per my example) are base 1.  If it assigned some other way, it is most likely base 0, so check to make sure that you're comparing the correct array index.

Comment: Hmm you are right. I am getting true through the msg box. Maybe it is because something is wrong with my array that I am using.

For i = 1 To 8
        If A = B(i) Then...
Next i

Comment: Yea StrComp is not supposed to compare like that. Thanks.

Comment: see some more info added, above. Maybe gets you closer to resolving issue (potentially) with your array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the help David