# VBA code to compare cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 worksheets(base) and a master worksheet (master) to compare with.

For each base worksheet, I need to compare the string value in each row for Col H (e.g.) to each row in master worksheet for Col G (e.g.). If the string value does not exist in the whole col G, the row in the base worksheet must be copied over to the master worksheet.

TIA!

Comment: You may want to start by showing what you have tried yourself. People here are always willing to help, but not so willing to do it for you with no visible attempt from you.

Comment: It could be done by looping through columns and using InStr or StrComp to compare cells (depending on how you want the comparison to be done. As DDuffy has said though, where have you got so far? People are happy to help but only if you show willingness to try and learn and persevere!

Comment: @DDuffy I asked because I had no idea where to begin but if you could suggest some places where I can read up on rather than saying stuff like "no visible attempt", it would be really great.

Comment: have you tried googling "VBA Compare string values"? the fourth result is an article on this site that will give you a good jumping off point. [See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370665/comparing-strings-in-vba)

Answer (score 1):

I think its easy enough the use the worksheet function Match which will error if the items doesn't exist so we handle the error. Here's my answer:

```
Sub MyCompare()
    Dim wksMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wksBases(2) As Worksheet
    Dim wksBase As Variant
    Dim intRowCountBase As Integer
    Dim intRowCountMaster As Integer
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngMasterColG As Range
    Dim intMatch As Integer

    'set up sheet vaiables
    Set wksMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    Set wksBases(0) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base1")
    Set wksBases(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base2")
    Set wksBases(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base3")

    'get the range of the master sheet col G
    intRowCountMaster = wksMaster.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rngMasterColG = wksMaster.Range(wksMaster.Cells(1, 7), wksMaster.Cells(intRowCountMaster, 7))

    'Loop through the base sheets
    For Each wksBase In wksBases
        intRowCountBase = wksBase.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'Loop through the cells in col H of the base sheet
        For Each rngCell In wksBase.Range(wksBase.Cells(1, 8), wksBase.Cells(intRowCountBase, 8))
            If rngCell.Value <> "" Then 'only do something if there is a value in the base sheet
                On Error Resume Next
                'the match value will error if the item doesn't exist
                intMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rngCell.Value, rngMasterColG, 0)
                If Err.Number > 0 Then ' ie there is no match
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    intRowCountMaster = intRowCountMaster + 1
                    'put the item on the master sheet
                    wksMaster.Cells(intRowCountMaster, 7).Value = rngCell.Value
                    'reset the master range
                    Set rngMasterColG = wksMaster.Range(wksMaster.Cells(1, 7), wksMaster.Cells(intRowCountMaster, 7))
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell

    Next wksBase

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would anyone mark my answer down when I have given a full working solution to the problem? If you aren't sure about anything, why not ask

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted, but some people here think it's not great form to provide detailed answer to a poorly written question, esp. when the OP has shown no sign of having made any effort. Basically, this OP has said "can someone write my code for free because I can't be bothered" and you've obliged him. It's possible that some might see that as encouraging more lazy or 'give me free code' questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reasoning Ambie. I understand but would think it would be kinder for people to comment that they don't think I should have given an answer rather than to rate it down which implies my answer doesn't work, which it does. I read the other original 2 comments before writing my answer and did so as when I was new to programming, there were times when I didn't really know where to start which may or not be the case here. I like to give people the benefit of doubt and work on the assumption the questioner wants to learn. I have lost 4 points today when I was just trying to be helpful

Comment: Just for the record, it wasn't me that down voted you either. If someone wants to give an answer that is their choice. I voted you up as i think answering this question is selfless and admirable. but hey.